# Make a responsive slider in mobile view not in a desktop view

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
 

.box{
 //border: thin black solid;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}

.box ol{
 margin:auto;
}

.box ol li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 margin: auto;
}

ol li img {
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <li>
  <img src="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v477/n7365/images/477415a-f1.2.jpg" width="80" height="80">
 </li>
 <li>
  <img src="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v477/n7365/images/477415a-f1.2.jpg" width="80" height="80">
 </li>
 <li >
  <img src="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v477/n7365/images/477415a-f1.2.jpg" width="80" height="80">
 </li>
 <li>
  <img src="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v477/n7365/images/477415a-f1.2.jpg" width="80" height="80" style="border:2px black solid;">
 </li>

 <li >
  <img src="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v477/n7365/images/477415a-f1.2.jpg" width="80" height="80">
 </li>
 <li >
  <img src="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v477/n7365/images/477415a-f1.2.jpg" width="80" height="80">
 </li>
 <li>
  <img src="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v477/n7365/images/477415a-f1.2.jpg" width="80" height="80">
 </li>

</ol>

</div>
```

I have n number of images. I have put images for testimonials.

When I see in mobile view then all the images should have manual slider and center image should be active with black border. so when I scroll on the image to the left or right then it should slide accordingly in the mobile view.

[image: Just like this]

so when I slide to left or right **manually** then the center image should be appeared as active.

Thank you.

Comment: you forgot the javascript code

Comment: which slider plugin you are using?

Comment: can I do it without plugin? I am using Bootstrap Carousel

Comment: you have to write script for slide. better you can use plugin

Comment: @madalinivascu... I don't know how to make slider in mobile view.

Answer (score 2):

you can write the code two times.

```
<div class="desktop-view">your code goes here</div>
<div class="mobile-view">your code goes here</div>
<style> /*hide mobile view for desktop view*/  
    .mobile-view {display:none}
      @media all and (max-width :767) {
      .desktop-view {
        display:none;
      }
     .mobile-view{ 
      display:block;
      }
     }

 </style>
```

Comment: i want to make a slider in  mobile view. for that what code should I write? can you provide with concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use owl Carousel. Owl carousel is responsive for both mobile and desktop.

Comment: but in our case , it is not responsive. i don't know why it is happening. we put a slider in mobile view, not in a desktop view.

Comment: you can write the code two times.
<div class="desktop-view">your code goes here</div>
<div class="mobile-view">your code goes here</div>
<style> /*hide mobile view for desktop view*/  
 .mobile-view{display:none}
 </style>